# Can't move a package

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I have a conflict between the g2o that I downloaded and the one that is pre-installed with ros-fuerte. I am trying to move the package libg2o to another folder. However when I right click, the move to and move to rubbish bin cannot be accessed.

Any Ideas on resolving this issue? thanks a lot.

Regards,

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50755/can%27t-move-a-package/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create an overlay as explained [here](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays). Then, check out g2o in there and build it.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1